# Why does Clang for arm64 move the frame pointer into itself before every objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue call when ARC is on?

Tags: objective-c, arm, clang

When ARC is on, clang for arm64 produces the following in between each `objc_msgSend` and corresponding `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue`:

```
MOV X29, X29
```

`X29` is, of course, the frame pointer; from what I can tell, this instruction does nothing.

Any idea why the compiler does this?

The only clue I could find in Google are the MAGIC and NOT_MAGIC definitions here: http://opensource.apple.com//source/objc4/objc4-680/test/rr-autorelease-fastarc.m . But that doesn't seem to elucidate much.

Comment: After 20 minutes of curious searching, [this blog](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/how-does-objc_retainautoreleasedreturnvalue-work/) seems enlightening. AFAICS, it would indeed appear to be a magic NOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the autorelease optimization mechanism.

```
static ALWAYS_INLINE bool callerAcceptsOptimizedReturn(const void *ra) {
// fd 03 1d aa mov fp, fp
// arm64 instructions are well-aligned
if (*(uint32_t *)ra == 0xaa1d03fd) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

If the statement at the return address is mov x29, x29, optimization can be performed. This statement is inserted by the compiler. When the compiler finds that the current control flow can be optimized, it will insert a mov x29, x29 after the branch jump statement as Optimization Flag to dynamically execute autorelease optimization logic at runtime.

The callee's recognition of the optimized caller is architecture-dependent.
x86_64: Callee looks for `mov rax, rdi` followed by a call or
jump instruction to objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue or
objc_unsafeClaimAutoreleasedReturnValue.

i386:  Callee looks for a magic nop `movl %ebp, %ebp` (frame pointer register)

armv7: Callee looks for a magic nop `mov r7, r7` (frame pointer register).

arm64: Callee looks for a magic nop `mov x29, x29` (frame pointer register).

[reference: https://developer.aliyun.com/article/713747]